# How do I make a list of cells that contain text from a table and avoid blanks? Index/Match/Lookup options (no VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-tables, excel-pivot

I have a table in excel set up like so:

| Procedure | Visit 1 | Visit 2 | Visit 3 | Visit 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arm |  | X | Z | X |
| Brain | X | Y | X |  |
| Chest |  |  | Z | Z |
| Eye | X | Y | X | Z |

I want to get be able to select information like so that I can filter to see what procedures marked X (or Y or Z) occur on what Visits. Basically I'd love for the output to look like this, skipping blanks.

| Arm (X) |
| --- |
| Visit 2 |
| Visit 4 |

| Eye (Z) |
| --- |
| Visit 4 |

I have tried this in countless ways in a pivot table and can't quite get it to look like I want. I'm on a work computer, so can't run VBA.

I can get this to work with LOOKUP, but I do a ton of these that are different size tables. Match/Index?

I'm sorry, my brain is fried.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to return the output like shown in the screenshot below, so you can see all the procedures where it has returned `X` or `Y` or `Z`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(G2=Table1[[Visit 1]:[Visit 4]],Table1[Procedure]),3),
 TOCOL(IFS(Table1[[Visit 1]:[Visit 4]]=G2,Table1[[#Headers],[Visit 1]:[Visit 4]]),3))
```

---

**Notes:** Please change the table names as per your suit.

[image]

---

Or,

```
=LET(
     α, TOCOL(IFS(G2=Table1[[Visit 1]:[Visit 4]],Table1[Procedure]&"|"&Table1[[#Headers],[Visit 1]:[Visit 4]]),3), 
     HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(α,"|"),TEXTAFTER(α,"|")))
```

---

Returning the output in a tabular layout is recommended, so it can be used in future to create a pivot tables or for other data manipulations, however here is another way, you could try as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, TOCOL(IFS(G2=Table15[[Visit 1]:[Visit 4]],Table15[Procedure]&"|"&Table15[[#Headers],[Visit 1]:[Visit 4]]),3),
     φ, TEXTBEFORE(α, "|"),
     δ, TEXTAFTER(α,"|"),
     uφ, UNIQUE(φ),
     HSTACK(uφ, BYROW(uφ, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(δ, x=φ))))))
```

---